# Automorphism of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

How can we show that every automorphism of $S_4$ is an inner automorphism ?

Comment: What are the index 4 subgroups of $S_4$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880776/operatornameauts-4-is-isomorphic-to-s-4

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

- Any automorphism preserves the conjugacy class of transpositions.( By counting size of conjugacy classes)
- Any automorphism preserves whether two transpositions share an element (by looking at the order of their product)
- Any automorphism permutes the four classes of transpositions {those that move 1}, {those that move 2}, {those that move 3}, {those that move 4}
- This gives you a permutation on {1,2,3,4} and it is not hard to show that your automorphism is conjugation by this permutation